# New line does not write to file when running python script from terminal

Tags: python

When running the Python file from an IDE (in my case VSCode) the program runs fine and formats the output to file without any issues. However, when I try to run the script from terminal, it seems to ignore the new line character in my output:

```
f = open(file_to_open + ".txt", "a+", buffering=1)
... other code
... start of loop
... code to retrieve variable values and convert to type string
f.write("{ " + ts + mc + im + ms + " }\n")
... end of loop
```

ts, mc, im, ms are just various string variables that have been created elsewhere in the code. These variables change over the course of the loop, with each iteration appending itself to the file. The new lines are intended to separate the iteration for readability.

Again, my only confusion is why it seems to run fine when running inside VSCode, but when executing the script in terminal:

```
python3 file.py
```

I don't receive the expected output. The program runs fine without errors, the difference is only in the output I receive in the text file.

EDIT: Fix was changing the `\n` special character to `\r\n`. Adding solution comment for context: VSCode will understand unix-style newlines (\n) but notepad.exe (for example) will not. Thank you to user: Blorgbeard.

Comment: do you mean new line at the end of file or between elements ? Show in question what you get and what you expect. Or maybe you should use `f.close()` at the end.

Comment: Or maybe you have two files with name `file.py` and you run different code in terminal. On linux you could use `cat file.py` to display code in terminal and check it.

Comment: There is only one .py file in the directory where I am running the script from. The f.write() command is in a loop where the variables that I am writing to file change each iteration through the loop. The \n character is intended to separate the iterations for readability as they are appended to the file.

Comment: Are you on windows? Are you viewing the file in the same program in both cases? If you are on windows, you may wish to write `\r\n` instead. VSCode will understand unix-style newlines (`\n`) but notepad.exe (for example) will not.

Comment: VSCode is running on Windows. When running the script from terminal, it was done in Ubuntu. Adding `\r\n` was able to provide the fix though. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Lennac: It’s not the terminal, it’s the OS; `\n` would be translated for you on Windows even if run from `cmd`.